# How do you get Cypress to open in Chrome and not Electron?

Tags: cypress

I swear when I use Cypress at work it opens in another Chrome window in the toolbar. When I use it at home it opens in another window in the CY (cypress toolbar) and it says Electron. I notice at home, I can't inspect elements or get to  the developers tools. What am I doing wrong? I have a win 7 machine. Is there some flag to make it open in Chrome instead? I am NOT talking about the run option I am opening the Cypress GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I downloaded chrome and re-installed it. Then I was able to choose Chrome from the drop down in Cypress and that fixed it. Odd indeed